# When mobile is rotated, width and height are swapped in get User Media Api JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile, landscape

I´m using the camera git getUserMedia(), but I have a big issue, because, I just set the video and height to 1280 and 720:

```
  videoConstraints.width = { min: 1280, ideal: 1280, max: 1280};
  videoConstraints.height = { min: 720, ideal: 720, max: 720};
```

It works perfect in a computer, and in a phone too, but the width and height are swapped on mobile, I have to use the mobile on landscape mode, in portrait mode the height is 1280 and width 720, and when is in landscape is height 720 and width 1280 (as I want), so i was looking for information for this, but i really does not found a really solution.

Reference to get user media API: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Reference to video constraints: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints/video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, then of face this problem i didnt found the problem, what i did was make custom styles with media queries for style mobile.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of landscape and portrait mode, if the view mode is portrait and the height is bigger than width, you should swap the width and the height.

```
const isPortrait = screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth;

const videoConstraints = {      
        video: {
          width:{ exact: isPortrait ? containerRef?.current?.offsetHeight : containerRef?.current?.offsetWidth},
          height:{ exact: isPortrait ? containerRef?.current?.offsetWidth : containerRef?.current?.offsetHeight}
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and [Alireza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78108592/23540218)'s answer helped me a lot.

> const isPortrait = **screen**.availHeight > **screen**.availWidth;

I first had **window** instead of **screen**.
Now everything works perfect :)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35744963)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of assigning an absolute width value via a HTML attribute in the tag of an image, assign the CSS rule max-width that targets the image as a percentage relative width value, like this: img {max-width:100%}

Try and see what happens.

Comment: Mmmm, I think thats not going to work, because exists a diference between the size of a canvas in the tag, this is the number of pixels it is going to have, and in css the size is  the area that it is going to occupe, anyway I am goint to try